# What is the difference between an on-policy distribution and state visitation frequency?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, sutton-barto, trust-region-policy-optimization, on-policy-distribution

On-policy distribution is defined as follows in Sutton and Barto:

[image]

On the other hand, state visitation frequency is defined as follows in [Trust Region Policy Optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf):

$$\rho_{\pi}(s) = \sum_{t=0}^{T} \gamma^t P(s_t=s|\pi)$$

**Question:** What is the difference between an on-policy distribution and state visitation frequency?

Comment: Where are you getting the definition of state visitation from, exactly (it's probably S&B again, but I'd like to know which chapter and section)? I am asking because the term is being defined for a purpose - also note unlike the distribution, its value can be above 1 for any given state.

Comment: Definition of state visitation is from TRPO paper.

Comment: In the TRPO paper, $\rho_{\pi}(s) = P(s_0=s) + \gamma P(s_1=s) + \gamma^2 P(s_2=s) + \dots$ and goes on forever not until $T$, at least, that's how it seems to be defined. You can find it under equation 1 and they don't call it exactly "state visitation frequency" but "(unnormalized) discounted visitation frequencies"

Answer (score 2):

**1.First of all**. The on-policy distribution $\mu(s)$ is a probability distribution. So, obviously, it is different from state visitation frequency $\rho_\pi(s)$, since $\rho_\pi(s)$ is not normalized to $1$. In the following discussion I'll assume that we are interested in the difference between TRPO's state visitation frequency $\rho_\pi(s)$ and Sutton and Barto's "time spent in a state" $\eta(s)$.

**2. Continuing task setting.** The TRPO paper you are referring to never considers episodic tasks and your expression for $\rho_\pi(s)$ is not present in the paper. So, first I'll derive the equality for discounted infinite sum. First, we start with basic MDP probability relations:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
P(s_0 = s) & = & h(s) \\
P(s_t = s) & = & \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}}P(s_{t-1} = \bar{s})\displaystyle\sum_{a}\pi(a|\bar{s})p(s|\bar{s},a) \quad \text{for}\quad t \ge 1 
\end{array}$$

The second equation can be derived using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and [marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Multiply the second equation by $\gamma^t$ and summing by $t$. Note that I'm summing form $t=1$ to infinity:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^tP(s_t = s) & = & \displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^t\displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}}P(s_{t-1} = \bar{s})\displaystyle\sum_{a}\pi(a|\bar{s})p(s|\bar{s},a)\\
 & = & \gamma \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^\infty \gamma^{t-1}P(s_{t-1} = \bar{s})\right)\displaystyle\sum_{a}\pi(a|\bar{s})p(s|\bar{s},a)
\end{array}$$
Next I'm adding the $P(s_0=s)=h(s)$ equation to both sides, and I'm shifting the summation bounds $(\sum_{t=1}^\infty \alpha_{t-1} = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \alpha_{t} )$ for the sum in curly brackets.
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^tP(s_t = s) & = & h(s) + \gamma \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^{t}P(s_t = \bar{s})\right)\displaystyle\sum_{a}\pi(a|\bar{s})p(s|\bar{s},a)
\end{array}$$
The expression in curly brackets is the same as expression on the lhs and the same as $\rho_\pi(s)$ (for $T=\infty$).

$$\rho_\pi(s) =  h(s) + \gamma \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}}\rho_\pi(\bar{s})\displaystyle\sum_{a}\pi(a|\bar{s})p(s|\bar{s},a)
$$

And that is the same equation as Sutton and Barto have for $\eta(s)$ - the "time spent in a state $s$". (They do mention the $\gamma$ factor in the quoted text.) So one can say that TRPO's $\rho_\pi(s)$ is the same as Sutton and Barto's $\eta(s)$ - at least in case of $T=\infty$.

**3. Episodic task setting.** In the episodic task setting (which is, again, is *not* considered in the TRPO paper) the derivation above is almost identical. A very important detail is the caveat that is mentioned in the quoted text: the whole expression is defined for the set of non-terminal states $s\in{\mathcal{S}}$. (Check the definitions of $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}^+$ in the section 3.3). The summation over $\bar{s}$ is, thus, also goes over $\mathcal{S}$ and this justifies the "shifting of the summation bounds" step in the derivation above:

$$ \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}\in\mathcal{S}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^T\gamma^{t-1}P(s_{t-1} = \bar{s})\right) \cdots = \displaystyle\sum_{\bar{s}\in\mathcal{S}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^T\gamma^{t}P(s_t = \bar{s})\right) \cdots$$

This works because $s_T$ is always the terminal state, so $P(s_T = \bar{s}) = 0$ and one can add this term to the sum.